# Raspberrypi won't start. LED's are on

Tags: boot, hdmi, led, boot-issues

I haven't used my RaspberryPi in month and today I wanted to start it, but my HDMI monitor doesn't get a signal. The LED 'OK' is shortly blinking at the beginning but then turns of. All the other LED's are on continously.

I've tried several settings of config.txt and two differnt OS. I have no problems using my SD-Card on my Laptop.

The last thing I did with my Raspberrypi is working with the GPIO, but everything worked just fine.

How do I boot my RaspberryPi and get a signal to my monitor

Answer (score 1):

I never got hdmi signal, so i change to rca (sdtv). You already try with another thing like analogic tv as mine ? If yes and you got signal, try rewrite the config.txt.
Take a look :
 http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: I only have a HDMI display, so I can't test it with anything else. But even with hdmi_safe = 1 I get no signal.

Comment: I still not get HDMI signal, then i tried somethings that i found away like put "tvservice -p" on terminal and repently i lost RCA signal but when i tried plug on HDMI cable say no signal...
Then i found it on internet that i think could help, but i dont tried yet, maybe in weekend.

 http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/04/10/getting-your-raspberry-pi-to-output-the-right-resolution.aspx

Comment: Hi again, i already tried and really works, now i have HDMI output...
The tutorial is here:
 http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/04/10/getting-your-raspberry-pi-to-output-the-right-resolution.aspx